"Warning" icon overlapping other on sign-in page upon inputting wrong credentials
When inputting wrong password and correct email in the Login page, I get a "warning" icon overlapping the show/hide password icon:



When inputting incorrect email, though, it doesn't overlap:



The email has to be correct in order to reproduce this bug.
Same happens on all other Stack Exchange sites.

Well that is just a poor graphic design choice, to put the icon inside the textbox. It "works" fine for short emails, and isn't noticeable, which is likely the reason nobody noticed until now. Doubt it's a bug (i.e. it's the design they applied on purpose) but meh, better be changed. (Slim chance for that but no harm asking. ;))
